# test class for custom controller extension

Tags: apex, unit-test

If I am building a test class for a custom controller, I generally start like this and I dont have any issues:

```
CustomControllerExtensionNameccn = new CustomControllerExtensionName();
```

However, as this custom controller is not an extension of a stadard controller, so the VF page will look like this:

```
    apex:page controller="CustomControllerName" extensions="CustomControllerExtensionName"
```

I cant use this system. After many hours of google I only found examples to test for custom controllers that are extensions of an standard controller, but not for custom controller

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
CustomControllerExtensionNameccn = new CustomControllerExtensionName();
```

Replace for

```
    CustomControllerExtensionName ccen = new CustomControllerExtensionName(new CustomControllerName());
```